# image hover effect not working when I use media query and change position from top

Tags: html, css

I am using media query to make my site responsive but when I adjust the screen size and adjust the value of the top position element the hover effect does not work. I have tried every thing but nothing seems to work. Please help, heres my code.

```css
    #getintouch{
     position: relative; 
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     background-color: #FFBA00;
     top: 400px;
    }
    
    .social-media-icon{
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     text-align: center;
    }
    
    
    .social-media-header{
     position: relative;
     text-align: center;
     margin: 5%;
     font-family: Lucida Calligraphy;
    }
    
    .social-media{
     position: relative;
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
     overflow: hidden;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 2% 5% 10% 5%;
    }
    
    
    .social-media a {
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .social-media img{
     transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .social-media img:hover{
     transform: translate3d(0, -80px, 0);
     }
    
    @media (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 760px){
    #getintouch{
      top: 900px;
     } 
    }
    
    @media(max-width: 759px){
     #getintouch{
      top: 1700px;
     }
    }
```

```html
    <div id="getintouch">
     <div class="social-media-header">
       <h1>Get In Touch</h1>
      </div>
    
     <div class="social-media-icon">
       <div class="social-media">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo/social-media-facebook.png" width="100%"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="social-media">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo/social-media-twitter.png" width="100%"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="social-media">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo/social-media-linkedIn.png" width="100%"></a>
       </div>
       <div class="social-media">
        <a href="#"><img src="logo/contact.png"  width="100%"></a>
       </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine in the example. If you don't experience the same effect on your page, that's most likely because you have other CSS-rules overriding or changing other aspects of the site.

Comment: it's good in the example. idk what is the problem.

Comment: Ok, its my code and its not working. Maybe its because overriding problem. But how do I know which element is causing the problem.

Comment: Please help and thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you forgot to add the following keywords: only, screen, and

> The only value is used if you want to hide the rule from older browsers that don't support the syntax; for browsers that do support it, only is effectively ignored.
>
> The screen keyword is a media type. It is used to specify that the media query is intended for color computer screens.

Apply the following changes to your stylesheet

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) and (min-width: 760px){
#getintouch{
        top: 900px;
    }   
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 759px){
    #getintouch{
        top: 1700px;
    }
}
```

In addition to that, make sure that you have the following meta tag

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```